# How to cast a parent type class to self class

Tags: java, android

I have specific classes like Car, Home adapter and they all extend to Adapter class, I pass their instance to setAdapterForList method, However, all the classes have special methods on their own, like buyCar, getHome.

What I want to do is, cast those adapters to their classes by getting their type in `setAdapterForList` method

```
listView.setAdapterForList(new CarAdapter(13));
```

This is what I want to do,

```
public void setAdapterForList(Adapter adapter) {
  // some how get their type from adapter, Eg. CarAdapter
  // and cast CarAdapter to it
  Type type = adapter.getType();
  Type typedAdapter = (type) adapter;
  typedAdapter.buyCar()
  setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Side note: if a method is called "setAdapterForList" why on earth do you call a method like buyCar() within? Adding something to a list should not have any other side effects ... than adding the thing to the list.

Comment: Regarding your question itself: there are only two choices. Either you do downcasts (very often a smell of bad design); or you use polymorphism.

Comment: @Jägermeister How can I do it with polymorphism ?

Comment: Well, by forgetting about having methods with different names. Instead you put some "doTheThing()" on your (potentially abstract) base class; an all your subclasses can provide a different implementation for doTheThing(). But you should really read some books, tutorials on OO design before starting to do OO design.

Comment: @Jägermeister Adapter is a native class in android, I have to extend Adapter class, I know what you are saying and I know how to do it, I am trying to find a smart way to do it, if you know what I mean

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if it can be done automatically.
But manually you can do like this:

```
CarAdapter carAd;
if (adapter instanceOf CarAdapter){
   carAd = (CarAdapter) adapter;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use instanceof, I would like to cast on the go, since there might be 5 or more adapters, can't I get the type with a method and cast to it instead without if else blocks ?

Comment: And what is "getType()" supposed to return? The point is that the compiler needs to know the specific class when you want to invoke class-specific methods.

Comment: @Jägermeister Opps!! Yes you are correct. My bad. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: getType supposed to return CarAdapter for example and I will cast to that variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `instanceof` to check wheter it is one or the other

```
public void setAdapterForList(Adapter adapter) {
  if (adapter instanceof Car) {
      Car c = (Car)adapter;
      // stuff
      return;
  }
  if (adapter instanceof Home) {
      Home h = (Home)adapter;
      // stuff
      return;
  }
  // and so on...
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use instanceof, I would like to cast on the go, since there might be 5 or more adapters, can't I get the type with a method and cast to it instead without if else blocks ?

Comment: Reality is not about what you want, but about what is possible. You can't cast "on the go" (well, you can, but then be prepared for ClassCastExceptions at run time)

Comment: If I can, well, maybe, you could tell me how I do it :)